# About an advantage of write through

Tags: caching, memory

I'm reading http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/CACHE/interac.html write through section:

> Advantage:
>    - **read miss** never results in writes to main memory

But I don't understand why read miss has anything to do with when talking about write through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writes are traditionally done lazily -- the value may be modified again while it's still in the cache, so there's no point writing any one change out to memory just yet. However, a read may require a dirty cache entry which hasn't yet been written out to memory to be evicted to make room, in which case that entry will have to be written to memory before the eviction can take place.

For a write-through cache, the modified value is written immediately on write, so cache entries are never dirty. Because of this, they can be evicted without writing without risk of data loss.

Comment: OK, so read miss may need to move something from MEM to Cache, and that may cause something in Cache be stored back to MEM?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 Exactly.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 Hopefully the rewrite is a bit clearer. The idea is if I do something like "x=4; x=5; x=6;", when the 4 gets written to the cache, it doesn't need to also write it out to memory because it's just going to be overwritten right away.